# Problems with script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code for tabs  on my website and it working just fine, but If I want to place same code on the page, tabs doesn't switch, when I click on the button it just sends me to the top and not switching. Can someone explain what can be the problem?

```
<center>
    <ul class="wpa_tab_pln" id="tab_lts_chp">
        <li style="text-align: center;float:none;display:inline-block"><a href="#" rel="tab_lts_chp_anm">button1</a></li>
        <li style="text-align: center;float:none;display:inline-block"><a class="selected" href="#" rel="tab_lts_chp_tv">button2</a></li>
        <li style="text-align: center;float:none;display:inline-block"><a class="selected" href="#" rel="tab_lts_chp_mng">button3</a></li>
        <li style="text-align: center;float:none;display:inline-block"><a class="selected" href="#" rel="tab_lts_chp_drama">button4</a></li>
    </ul>
</center>

<div class="clr"></div>

<div style="display:block" id="tab_lts_chp_anm" class="wpa_tab_ctt">Shortcode</div>
<div style="display:none" id="tab_lts_chp_tv" class="wpa_tab_ctt">shortcode</div>
<div style="display:none" id="tab_lts_chp_mng" class="wpa_tab_ctt">shortcode</div>
<div style="display:none" id="tab_lts_chp_drama" class="wpa_tab_ctt">shortcode</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tab_lts_chp_obj = new wpm_tab("tab_lts_chp");

    tab_lts_chp_obj.set_pst(true);                                                
    tab_lts_chp_obj.set_sel_cls_tgt("link");                              
    tab_lts_chp_obj.inl();
</script>
```

This script is working if I put it once. If I put same code on the page second time, second copy won't work.

Comment: where is the switching script?

Comment: Obviously it's a javascript error, see developer's console.

Comment: You should reference the div you want to be displayed in the function being used and use `show` method. Something like `function showDiv(idDiv) { $("#" + idDiv).show(); }`.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi `$(...)` syntax is used by jQuery. It is ***not*** native JavaScript. What gives you any indication that the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: You're correct, I assumed it.

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute is not pointing anywhere.

Comment: It is supposed to be scripted, the script will use the rel attribute

Comment: it doesnt need to be pointed. It's working with  shortcodes. So when I click on the button it wont send me on another page it just will show different information on the same page.